# Windows & Squid usage correlation (logs)

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, logging, correlation, squid

For a project, I am required to correlate proxy (Pfsense + Squid) requests made by Windows users, through logs.

I just need to know, which user is using the proxy, with the request

Here are my environment details:

- Logs are gathered and indexed in Elastic cluster (ELastic + Kibana + Fleet & Agents).
- Multiple users can be on the same Windows server (from 5 to 10), so they can make multiple requests at the same time.
- There is NO authentication for the proxy, you can use it just with IP:port
- I do not have the possibility to get DNS and browser logs (on Windows server)
- I cannot set up user auth. or make any changes to the proxy.

**EDIT**: I used the squid integration for Elastic Agents (https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/squid)

I searched for different ways to get these information from Windows, but I did not found a way.

Also search in the different procotols that squid use ([link](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/AboutSquid#what-other-squid-related-documentation-is-available)), nothing.

Do you have any clues ? Or is it even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the pfsense integration and collect the logs with elastic agents? It looks like you can collect `source.user.full_name` if exist.
https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/pfsense

Comment: Hi, I used the squid integration (https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/squid) as I am only interested in the squid logs.
But for the `source.user.full_name`, I think that is related to the user that connects to the pfsense GUI/CLI or any pfsense related functionalities (firewall, vpn, ...). I'll look into it to be sure